# Create JS Function and Use Later in Firefox Browser

Tags: firefox, browser

Is there a way to write a JS function and then use it later in your browser on any web page? I know I've seen things like this before but can't manager to find it on the web.

So, let's say I have this function I found on StackOverflow that will convert a `JSON` string to a `x-www-urlencoded` string.

```
var toWWWFormEncoded = (params) => {
    var query = "";
    for (key in params) {
        query += encodeURIComponent(key)+"="+encodeURIComponent(params[key])+"&";
    }
    return query
}
```

Where can I store it and how would I use it after storing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox supports "bookmarklets" which are java snippets that run on the current page as if you run them from the developer console.

Firefox help on how to use and install them is at [Use bookmarklets to quickly perform common web page tasks](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarklets-perform-common-web-page-tasks)

There is a site with a catalogue of bookmarklets at [Marklets](http://marklets.com/)